# Django Unittesting: How to create temporary test only view?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, django-testing

I'm writing a django app which includes a utility to extract information from a html table on some url and downloads some files accordingly (assume  the function is named `extract_table_do_x`). To test this utility I want to create a temporary page with a mock html table and run `extract_table_do_x` on it, but I don't want this page to be part of the main app. How to do so?

Comment: You don't need a view to test this.  Just pass some canned html content directly to your utility.

Comment: Canned html will work fine for testing table extraction part but not for testing the downloading part of the utility.

Comment: If you want to test the downloading part, it is no longer a unit test, but an integration test.